# Compare parts of a date against row in mysql including keywords

Tags: php, date, search, mysqli

I am trying to compare a date stored as a variable against a row in mysql, this is where i am so far:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['date1'])) {
$datum = $_REQUEST['date1'];
   if($datum == "0000-00-00") {$datum = "";}
echo "Date: $datum";
echo "<br>";
} else { $datum = ""; }


$result = mysqli_query($link, " SELECT id, auditor, auditee, datum, department, func, proc, audit_type, copy_to, comments 

FROM audit_data

WHERE 
( 
`auditor` LIKE '%$search_field%' OR 
`auditee` LIKE '%$search_field%' OR 
`department` LIKE '%$search_field%' OR 
`func` LIKE '%$search_field%' OR 
`proc` LIKE '%$search_field%' OR 
`audit_type` LIKE '%$search_field%')
OR
(`id` = '$radio_id')
OR
(`datum` LIKE '%$datum%')
" ) 
OR 
die(mysqli_error($link));
```

I am unable to get the query to return the row with the requested date.

$datum is stored as YYYY-MM-DD
`datum` is the same.

I have tried everything! What the hell am I doing wrong??

Comment: you can search dates using LIKE as well

Comment: Awesome, how would that work? Replace "0000" with a wildcard?

Comment: or, you can compare them as numbers, using <, > or BETWEEN

Comment: @Your Common Sense could you elaborate these as the answer so i can accept. - Thank you!

Comment: @YourCommonSense i tried your comments but still nothing, it must be fundamental but what!? ahhh!

Comment: What certainly did you try? What is the data in DB? What is the data from request? What query did you try?

Comment: @YourCommonSense OK so i tried formatting $datum like date('$datum'), tried explode() $datum into an array and matching $datum[0] etc against `datum` with LIKE (long shot). Tried matching it in varchar format instead of date. Other than that i tried to do a separate query, get all the date columns into an array and match them against $datum then parse that to the second query but it just go out of hand so I gave up pulling my hair out, please help me sort this before I run out of hair.

Comment: @YourCommonSense What is the data in DB? - data in the database is all varchar apart from the date. If thats what your asking.
What is the data from request? - Can you rephrase this please?

Comment: Have also tried matching the column to var with Day()/Month()/Year() functions and DATE_FORMAT function. Still nothing.